# XeLaTeX Section related page/figure numbering

Tags: sectioning, xetex, page-numbering

Is there any good method to get section related page and figure numbering which also allows a consistant TOC/TOF?

I am using the article class to write a technical manual.

Section 1, Page numbering shall start with 1-1, 1-2 and so on. Section 2, 2-1, 2-2 etc.
Same for figures.

I found a lot of references to the chappg package but it doesn't seems to fit the requirements.
on}

Update: Code example modified based on David's help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``---''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text of 150 paragraphs
%*******************************HEADER LAYOUT*******************************
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%Rewriting thepage to show section related numbering
\renewcommand\thepage{\thesection--\arabic{page}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
%*******************************SECTION OPTIONS*******************************
%Begin each section with a new page & reset numbering on each section.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Getting started}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\section{Operational Principles}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum
\section{Forms}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-50]
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do your sections start a new page? (article class sections by default do not)

Comment: Yes I got some code in my doc for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is why questions should *always* include a complete small document that shows the problem.

For the page number case you need to modify the code that forces a page break to add `\setcounter{page}{1}` I can't show exactly where as it depends on your local code.

Then add

```
\renewcommand\thepage{\thesection--\arabic{page}}
```

For figures you can use

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}
 \makeatletter
 \@addtoreset {figure}{section}
 \makeatletter
```

---

In the example you added, the page break is coming too late, the section counter has already been incremented so the last page of each section is wrong.

`titlesec` doesn't seem to help much in this case (but I left it in in case your real example uses more of the package features) it is simpler just to add the `\clearpage` directly to `\section`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\oldsection}
```

Comment: Added a small example what I am doing above. Very close to the solution, but still does some strange numbering. Section 1: 1-1 then 2-2, Section 2: 2-1, 2-2 which is fine, but then 3-3. Section 3 looks good.

Comment: @Bax see updated answer